# Using a variable inside a print

Tags: theming

I have the following code:

```
print $node->field_carousel_1[0]['filepath'];
```

What I would like to do is changing the 1, and use a variable instead.

Do you have any idea how I would be able to do this?

What I am aiming for is using a variable to create a looping function to print
"field_carousel_1," "field_carousel_2," "field_carousel_3," etc.

Comment: This is not a Drupal question, but rather a PHP question. Drupal Answers is for questions specific for Drupal; in this case, the answer is not different if it would be asked about Wordpress, or plain PHP code.

Comment: Ok, i will post this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Check there isn't already a similar question, first. It is probable somebody already asked a similar question, and the answer is a feature present in PHP.

Comment: I would argue that Sam's use case means that it is a valid question for Drupal.SE.  How many other questions on Drupal.SE come down to being PHP issues?

Comment: @Chapabu `$node->{$property}` is plain PHP. It is not something you can use only on Drupal, such as calling `drupal_render()`.

Comment: I'm afraid I still have to disagree.  Sam is dealing with fields, and there may very well have been field API functions for his use case.  You don't know unless you ask.

Comment: @Chapabu In that case, you should provide an answer about Drupal API, not about PHP features.

Comment: I said there MIGHT have been, not there WAS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the 1 to your particular variable in the loop.

Example:

```
foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
  print $node->field_carousel_ . $v . [0]['filepath'];
}
```

That should output the values you need.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i actually get a syntax error on the print line there, any ideas why?

Comment: I've edited my answer...try it now, it's only really an example and you may have to modify it for your use case.  It also may be slightly wrong as I'm on my phone at the moment ;-)

Comment: It doesn't work, as PHP will try to access `$node->field_carousel_`, convert it to a string, and concatenate it with `$v`. It should also return you a syntax error.